# Set a variable to be seen by all activities using javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I need to set a variable to be seen by all the activities in the app using javascript loaded in a webview.
I've tried binding javascript but it's not working.

```
package xxxx.xxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebAppInterface extends Activity {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        // set
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setIdUser("foo2");
        // get
    }
}
```

I'v also tried without "extends Activity" but I get this error: Cannnot resolve method 'getApplication()'

Here it's the JavaScript and HTML code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }

</script>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
```

The toast is showed but the global variable is not set.

Comment: then show what you've tried

Comment: where is your webview?

Comment: The webview is in the MainActivity. Do yo need me to post it?

Comment: I updated the post with the JS and HTML code

Comment: You can have static variable userid in your class and set its value in the showToast() method, this way it will be accessible in other classes